# How to print current timestamp in C++

Tags: c++, time, printf, c++-chrono, ctime

I currently have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>  

int main() {
printf("%i", time(0));
return 0;
}
```

Compile with gcc:

```
gcc source.cpp -o program
```

Error:

```
/tmp/ccTUJX4u.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
source.cpp:(.text+0x1a9): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
source.cpp:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I just want to print the current timestamp I tried stuff with the chrono and ctime modules but nothing works is it really that hard to print the current time in C++?

Please help

Comment: To build C++ programs use the command `g++` instead of `gcc`. The `g++` command will add some linker options, like linking with the C++ run-time library.

Comment: You should `#include <cstdio>` if you want to use `printf`

Comment: That really fixed it. Man I cant believe that. Thanks